# Is there a vector class or struct (with 3 components) in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a good available vector class or struct (for vectors defined in physics with 3 components) in C#? It is like `c++`'s `std::array<double, 3>` and better with inner product, cross product and other arithmetic operations.

Comment: Look at the [Vector3 structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector3(v=vs.111).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Icemanind pointed out in his comment to your question, the `System.Numerics` namespace has some `Vector` classes that provide some support for basic algebric operations over vectors.

IMHO, using a library like http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ gives you a lot more options in terms of operations, storage, formats, integration with other mathematical entities, etc. All included in a single library with a common and convenient API. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use class `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`.

Additional information at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This provides none of the requested features of "inner product, cross product, and other arithmetic operations."